# Test Django settings with pytest

Tags: python, django

I am trying to set some environment variables that drive the configuration of a Django project in some tests so that I can mock some of the values and make assertions easier and explicit.

I want to set an environment variable with the name of a file which stores some configuration which is loaded if the variable is set and the file exists. i.e:

```py
# proj.settings.py

CONFIG = None
if _filename := os.environ.get('FILE_PATH', None):
    with open(_filename) as f:
        CONFIG = json.load(f)
```

I have tried a fixture that sets an environment variable (see `set_env`), so my tests look like this:

```py
# some_app.tests.test_settings.py

import os

@fixture
def data_raw():
    return dict(
        foo="bar"
    )

@fixture
def data_file(data_raw):
    with NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w+") as f:
        json.dump(data_raw, f)
        yield f.name

@fixture
def set_env(data_file):
    os.environ['FILE_PATH'] = data_file

def test_it_loads_data(set_env, data_raw, settings):
    assert settings.CONFIG == data_raw
```

But `set_env` doesn't execute before Django's configuration, so `CONFIG` is never set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django settings run at import time, therefore it will be executed before any fixture.

You could probably work around it by setting the environment variable at import time as well:

```py
os.environ['FILE_PATH'] = ...

def test_it_loads_data(set_env, data_raw, settings):
    assert settings.CONFIG == data_raw
```

But having said that, I don't think this is the best approach to test this. I think it's preferable to move that logic into a separate function and then test it by itself:

```py
# utils.py
def loan_config():
    if _filename := os.environ.get('FILE_PATH', None):
        with open(_filename) as f:
            return json.load(f)
    return None

# settings.py
CONFIG = loan_config()
```

Then you test the `load_config` by itself:

```py
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
import json

def test_load_config():
    mock_data = {"key": "value"}

    # Create a temp file with the mock data
    with NamedTemporaryFile("w", suffix=".json", delete=False) as temp_file:
        json.dump(mock_data, temp_file)
        temp_file.close()

        # Store the temp file path in an env variable
        os.environ["FILE_PATH"] = temp_file.name

        # Call the loan_config function
        result = loan_config()

        # Assert that the function returns the file parsed by json
        assert result == mock_data

        # Clean up the temp file
        os.remove(temp_file.name)
```

You should also probably restore the previous value of the FILE_PATH env after the test is finished. Otherwise, this will be a "leaky" test